# innerhtml only changes on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a group of panels that I would like to expand individually when clicked upon, but also if the user clicks on Expand + the text should change to Collapse and all panels should expand. Currently, this only works on the second click. I have also tried using "toggle".
Expected functionality:
Click on Expand + the the text changes to Collapse - and all panels regardless if they are currently being shown should collapse
Click on Collapse - and all panels regardless if they are currently being shown should display.

```js
function travelAccordion() {

  var x = document.getElementById("travelClick");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Expand All +") {
    x.innerHTML = "Collapse All -";
    $('#travel-accordion .collapse').collapse('show');
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Expand All +";
    $('#travel-accordion .collapse').collapse('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
.panel-title:hover,
#travelClick {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p class="text-right" id="travelClick" onclick="travelAccordion()"> Expand All +</p>
<div class="panel-group" id="travel-accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#travel-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Group 1</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse1" style="">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Group 1 Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#travel-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Group 2</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse2" style="">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Group 2 Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works fine in this snippet

Comment: @ChrisG no, if you click "Expand All +" it won't expand until the second time it's clicked.

Comment: You would be much better off toggling a class and checking for that, doing an exact match to `innerHTML` is a pretty fragile approach (e.g. something as simple as a change in the whitespace would break your functionality)

Comment: Yes, and here's a great example why that would be better: your code does not work because the *initial* value of the `<p>` has a **space character** before the word "Expand".

Comment: Ironically, after looking at your code, a whitespace issue is exactly what's causing this. You have a space before your "Expand All +"

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery anyway, mixing in straight browser API calls is confusing.

Comment: Debug.  Check that what you're comparing *is* what you *expect* it to be - `console.log("[" + x.innerHTML + "]")` and you'll see it has extra spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to post a formal answer, building off DBS's comment. A whitespace in the html content of your "#travelClick" element is causing the issue. Using an HTML content selector can be unreliable, and instead you should use either a class or data attribute to keep track of the state of the accordion.

Here is an example:

```js
function travelAccordion() {
  var x = $("#travelClick");
  var isExpanded = x.data("expanded"); // Get the current state

  if (isExpanded) {
    x.html("Expand All +");
    $('#travel-accordion .collapse').collapse('hide');
  } else {
    x.html("Collapse All -");
    $('#travel-accordion .collapse').collapse('show');
  }

  x.data("expanded", !isExpanded); // Toggle the state
}

// Initial setup
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#travelClick").data("expanded", false); // Set initial state
});
```

```css
.panel-title:hover,
#travelClick {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p class="text-right" id="travelClick" onclick="travelAccordion()"> Expand All +</p>
<div class="panel-group" id="travel-accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#travel-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Group 1</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse1" style="">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Group 1 Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#travel-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Group 2</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse2" style="">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Group 2 Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```